# Sufficient condition for strict local minimum of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let's try this again.
Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$, $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X\in D$. By a derivative in the direction of nonzero vector $\bf{v}$ we mean
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(X+h{\bf{v}})-f(X)}{h} $$ 
if such a limit exists we'll denote the result as $\mbox{D}_{\bf{v}}f(X)$
Note that when we pick direction as vector $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ we obtain the partial derivatives at point $X$. It is also known that a directional derivative can be computed by a certain scalar product:
$$\mbox{D}_{\bf{v}}f(X) = \left\langle \nabla f(X), \frac{\bf{v}}{\|\bf{v}\|} \right\rangle $$

**The problem**
Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $A\in\mbox{Int}D$ and let there exist $r>0$ s.t
$$X\in B(A,r), X\neq A \Longrightarrow \mbox{D}_{\bf{AX}}f(X) >0 \tag{*}\label{eq:1}$$
*Can we assume that this implication guarantees the existence of derivative in any direction?*

> Show that for any $X\in B(A,r), X\neq A$ we have $f(X)>f(A) $.

In a single variable case, if we have $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g$ continuous at $a,b$ and $g'(x)>0$ for any $x\in (a,b)$ we can immediately say that $g$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and therefore for any $x\in (a,b]$ we can find $c\in (a,x)$ such that
$$g(x)-g(a) = g'(c)(x-a)>0 $$
and conclude that $g(a)$ is the minimum.

In multiple variable case, my hope is to achieve something similar. To be precise, the mean value theorem is as follows:
Let $g:E\to\mathbb{R}$, $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be continuous at $X, X+v$, $v:=(v_1,v_2)$ and differentiable in the straight line $[X, X+v]$ that connects these points. Then there exists $C\in (X,X+v)$ such that
$$g(X+v)-g(X) = g_x(C)v_1+g_y(C)v_2 $$
*The proof doesn't actually utilize the dimension of the domain, so I suppose it remains valid for any arbitrary finite dimensional domain*

**An attempt**
The following assumes that \eqref{eq:1} guarantees existence of derivatives in arbitrary direction
By \eqref{eq:1}, for any $X\in B(A,r), X\neq A$ we have $\mbox{D}_{\bf{AX}}f(X)>0$, which means
$$\left\langle \nabla f(X),\frac{\bf{AX}}{\|\bf{AX}\|}\right\rangle >0\Longrightarrow f_x(X)(x-a)+f_y(X)(y-b)>0 $$
where $X = (x,y), A = (a,b)$.
If $f$ was differentiable in the entire $B(A,r)$, the the result would be immediate from MVT. For diffentiability, it is sufficient for $f$ to have continuous partial derivatives, but we only know they exist at every point, not that they are necessarely continuous (*right?*).

**An idea**
If we pick an arbitrary direction w.r.t to point $A$, let's say it's determined by the vector ${\bf{u}}\neq 0$, then we could view a "cut" or a "section" of the function $f$ which we could define by
$$f_{\bf{u}}(t) := f(a+tu_x, b+tu_y) $$
*imagine we slice the surface $f$ with a plane that is perpendicular to the $x,y$ plane, passes through $A$ and follows the direction of $\bf{u}$*
However, we must choose the parameter $t$ such that $A+t\bf{u}$ leaves point $A$ in only one direction.
The derivative of such a function at some point $A+t\bf{u}$ is precisely the directional derivative of $f$ at $A+t{\bf{u}}$ and now we can apply single variable MVT for the entire family of such functions and conclude that $f(A)$ has to be the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:This follows from the $1$-dimensional case, consider $h_X:I\rightarrow R^n$ defined $h_X(t)=A+tX$ where $h_X(I)$ is in the domain of $f$ and $f(h_X(t))$, its derivative at $0$ $d_{AX}f>0$. This implies that $h\circ f$ increases in $I$, remark that $A$ is not a minimum, because you cannot have $d_{AX}f(X)>0$ and $d_{A(-X)}f=-d_{AX}f>0$. In fact you can characterize local extremums like in the $1$-dimensional case here if $f$ is defined on $B(A,r)$, and is differentiable, then $df_{AX}f=0$ for every $X$ if $A$ is a local minimum.

For the situation $g:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ with $g'(x)>0, x\in (a,b)$ $a$ can be a minimum because $a$ is not in the interior of the domain of $g$.

Comment: Oh, that is clever!